# C# MediaPlayer.MediaEnded event not firing

Tags: c#, events, system.windows.media

i have this little piece of C# code

```
//Creates a MediaPlayer with the sound you want to play
    public static void PlaySound (Stream wavStream, string wavName, bool loop)
    {
        //Get the path for the file to play
        var path = GetFilePath(wavStream, wavName);

        var player = new MediaPlayer();
        player.Open(new Uri(path));
        player.MediaEnded += loop ? new EventHandler(MediaEndedLoop) : new EventHandler(MediaEndedDestroy);
        player.Play();

        players.Add(player);
        names.Add(wavName);
    }
```

I dont know why but MediaEndedLoop and MediaEndedDestroy are never called

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem.  I couldn't find a solution, but I did come up with a workaround if your media exists in a looping application or thread.  You can just manually reset the position after a certain point.

```
if (media.Position > new TimeSpan(0, 2, 25))
      {
          media.Position = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 00);
      }
```

That's the best I can offer as of now.

Answer (score 1):

The `MediaPlayer` requires a `Dispatcher` in order to dispatch the `MediaEnded`, `MediaOpened` ... events.

When you are using a WinForm application a `Dispatcher` should already have been registered. That means that you should not have to do anything to get the events working.

If you want to receive events in a console application you'll have to run the `Dispatcher` yourself.

```
public static void Main (string[] args)
{
  var mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
  mediaPlayer.MediaEnded += (sender, eventArgs) => Console.WriteLine ($"ended.");
  mediaPlayer.MediaOpened += (sender, eventArgs) => Console.WriteLine ($"started.");
  mediaPlayer.MediaFailed += (sender, eventArgs) => Console.WriteLine ($"failed: {eventArgs.ErrorException.Message}");
  mediaPlayer.Changed += (sender, eventArgs) => Console.WriteLine ("changed");

  mediaPlayer.Open (new Uri (@"S:\custom.mp3"));
  mediaPlayer.Play();

  Dispatcher.Run();
}
```